# Draw text inside pylab figure window

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to add some more details about the calculations used to create a plot (histogram).

How can I add some text that I can position anywhere I want in the figure window?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Lots of ways to do this:

- [text](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.text)
- [figtext](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.figtext)
- [annotate](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.annotate)

Comment: I ended up using `text`, what I didn't realize before I asked the question was that the x,y coords for the figure window range from 0-1.