# add label to subplot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there an automatic way to add pure labels to the subplots? To be specific, I used

```
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
```

and I would like to add 'A' and 'B' to the upper right in the subplots to distinguish them, and right now I am using a dummy way something like

```
ax1.annotate('A', xy=(2, 1), xytext=(1, 22))
ax2.annotate('B', xy=(2, 1), xytext=(1, 22))
```

I tried using

```
ax1.legend()
```

and that also gives me "small images" of lines or dots before the letter and I do not need that image.

Comment: This section of the matplotlib user guide might be helpful: http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html#axes-coordinates

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `annotate`, but you'll need to set the correct limits so they are in the "upper right corner". If you call the annotate commands after you've made all the plots, this should work since it pulls the limits from the axis itself.

```
import pylab as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)

def get_axis_limits(ax, scale=.9):
    return ax.get_xlim()[1]*scale, ax.get_ylim()[1]*scale

ax1.annotate('A', xy=get_axis_limits(ax1))
ax2.annotate('B', xy=get_axis_limits(ax2))
plt.show()
```

[image]

It's also worth looking at [the other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5812349/249341) to put text on the figure.

Comment: I just add more arguments `def get_axis_limits(ax, x_scale=.7, y_scale=0.7)` in my codes and that may allow more freedom. @Hooked

Answer (score 9):

You can skip writing a helper function and just call:

```
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)

ax1.annotate("A", xy=(0.9, 0.9), xycoords="axes fraction")
ax2.annotate("B", xy=(0.9, 0.9), xycoords="axes fraction")
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer by hooked works, but keep in mind that you need to scale the position properly.

```
def text_coords(ax=None,scalex=0.9,scaley=0.9):
  xlims = ax.get_xlim()
  ylims = ax.get_ylim()
  return {'x':scalex*np.diff(xlims)+xlims[0],
        'y':scaley*np.diff(ylims)+ylims[0]}


scalex = [0.02,0.02,0.75,0.75]
scaley = [0.02,0.75,0.02,0.75]
labels = ['(a)','(b)','(c)','(d)']

f,ax = plt.subplots(2,2)
for sx,sy,a,l in zip(scalex,scaley,np.ravel(ax),labels):
   a.text(s=l,**text_coords(ax=a,scalex=sx,scaley=sy))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[labels demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHwn6.png)

Answer (score 0):

Matplotlib (version 3.4.2) has a function to help with this: [`pyplot.subplot_mosaic`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot_mosaic.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplot_mosaic).

See the example [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/label_subplots.html) which demonstrates how to produce the following:
[image]