# Place labels both inside and outside of axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

As I have very long string labels and some other shorter labels for one axis, I would like to place the long labels outside and the short labels inside the axis. Is that possible?

A basic example would be this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.boxplot(np.random.randn(100), vert=0) 
longlabs = ['foofoofoofoofoofoofoo']
shortlabs= ['bar']
ax.yaxis.set_ticklabels(longlabs)
```

Where/how to place `shortlabs` at the inner side of the axis?

Comment: The line `ax.yaxis.set_yticklabels(longlabs)` does not run.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo - one "y" too much. I edited my question. Thank you!

Comment: Embarrassingly, I could not produce a graph of the boxplot to actually look at. It showed an empty plot. Without knowing more, could you instead draw text inside the plot: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812169/draw-text-inside-pylab-figure-window ?

Comment: That's what I kept in mind as a workaround. However, it would be nice if there was no trouble aligning the text to the ticks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
longlabs = ['foofoofoofoofoofoofoo  bar']
ax.yaxis.set_ticklabels(longlabs,position=(0.06,0))
```

But I think you should use vertical alignment for long text:

```
ax.yaxis.set_ticklabels(longlabs, rotation='vertical')
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

ticklabels are not the same as labels. a trick that looks good on this example :

```
ax.yaxis.set_label_coords(.05,0.5)
ax.yaxis.set_label_text('foooooooooooooooooooooo\n\nbar')
```